# How to deal with a customer who get work and didn't gave payment?

Tags: freelance-websites, payment-terms

I'm logo designer.

A few days ago a customer contacted me through a freelancing site he order me to make a logo for his product.  I made a logo for him.  He said to make it better.  I did and delivered it but he cancelled order by saying that it is not up to his standard and I didn't get payment.  After a day, I saw my logo on his site.

How to deal with such customers who didn't pay and get work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most freelance sites have an arbitration clause for this type of thing. Screenshot the logo being used and contact the proper support channel on said freelance website. It'll take a while but they usually either succeed in getting you paid or in the client ceasing to use your work.

Answer (score 2):

**You sue them.** There's really not much else to be done.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable Answer But how i wil sue them as there is no legal contract between us

Comment: No emails? no texts? No instant messages? Nothing in writing whatsoever? No way to prove you created the artwork? If that's true, then you learn from the experience and move on. There's nothing you *can* do.

Comment: No, i  have his chat where i get his  requirements but is this enough to take him to court?

Comment: Location matters. In the US, sometimes *any* written evidence that he requested work and that you completed that work may be favorable to a court judgement. At times even verbal agreements *may* be enough for small claims court with some evidence to back things up. **I am not a lawyer**. and I *am not* giving any legal advice other than to point out if you want to get paid, you have to prove you are owed. You may wish to speak to an attorney. I'm uncertain what you anticipate anyone here posting. There's no "magic" button to force a client to be suddenly honest and forthright with payment.